# The words "request an account merge" are repeated on the my account Help Center page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The words "request an account merge" appear twice in succession, initially not as a link and then as a link at the end of the final paragraph on [the new my account help page](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/openid-endpoint).